# minimize the repeated code using PHP function

Tags: php, joomla

I want to minimize a repeated php code using function, I am a designer and now I am trying to learn PHP.
below code check if a Module block is active, and count blocks,

```
$TopCol1 = (int)($this->countModules('top-col-1') > 0);
$TopCol2 = (int)($this->countModules('top-col-2') > 0);
$TopCol3 = (int)($this->countModules('top-col-3') > 0);

$topColCount = $TopCol1 + $TopCol2 + $TopCol3;
if ($topColCount) : $TopColClass = 'count-' . $topColCount; 
endif;
```

Then below code will be processed

```
    <?php if ($topColCount) : ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php if ($this->countModules('top-col-1')) : ?>    
        <div id="top-col" class="<?php echo $TopColClass ?> columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-col-1" style="html5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($this->countModules('top-col-2')) : ?>    
        <div id="top-col" class="<?php echo $TopColClass ?> columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-col-2" style="html5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($this->countModules('top-col-3')) : ?>    
        <div id="top-col" class="<?php echo $TopColClass ?> columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-col-3" style="html5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I need to repeat this type of code many time in my template, please help me make a function that will create the blocks without repeating this codes again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't recommend the syntax, you can put raw HTML code inline inside a php function.

```
<?php
function code_block( $jdoc_name ) {
global $TopColClass;  //// for variables created outside the function to be visible inside it, we have to include them with "global"
?>
<div id="top-col" class="<?php echo $TopColClass; ?> columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php echo $jdoc_name; ?>" style="html5" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

$MODULES = array(
  'top-col-1',
  'top-col-2',
  'top-col-3',
);


//// ....


//// in the page body a foreach loop would also be a good idea:
foreach( (array)$MODULES as $module_name ) {
    if ($this->countModules( $module_name )) {
        code_block( $module_name );
    }
}


?>
```

---

EDIT, to solve as requested:

```
<?php
function code_block( $jdoc_name ) {
global $TopColClass;  //// for variables created outside the function to be visible inside it, we have to include them with "global"
?>
<div id="top-col" class="<?php echo $TopColClass; ?> columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php echo $jdoc_name; ?>" style="html5" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

function module( $prefix, $comma_seperated_suffixes ) {
    foreach( (array)explode( ",", $comma_seperated_suffixes ) as $suffix ) {
        $module_name = $prefix.trim($suffix);
        code_block( $module_name );
    }
}


//// shorter call, as requested :)
module("top-col-", "1,2,3");


?>
```

---

Final Edit, transformed into a class

```
<?php
class tovolt{
    function tovolt() {
        //// constructor function - used to setup default variable states, etc. - if this is omitted PHP may have a fit ( depending on version and config )
    }

    public static $TopColClass = 'default-value';

    function code_block( $jdoc_name ) {
?>
<div id="top-col" class="<?php echo self::$TopColClass; ?> columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php echo $jdoc_name; ?>" style="html5" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }

    function module( $prefix, $comma_seperated_suffixes ) {
        foreach( (array)explode( ",", $comma_seperated_suffixes ) as $suffix ) {
            $module_name = $prefix.trim($suffix);
            self::code_block( $module_name );
        }
    }
}


//// calling the class
tovolt::$TopColClass = 'new-value';                //// if you need to change: $TopColClass
tovolt::module("top-col-", "1,2,3");

?>
```

Comment: instead of modules name in array, is it possible that I will assign a name and blocks like this `module("top-col-", "1,2,3")`. It will be very helpful then

Comment: You mean like this? ( updated answer below original )

Comment: thanks for your great contribution. I am making an opensource joomla framework, I am expert in designing and VisualStudio but poor in PHP code. if you like to contribute to project you are welcome. here is the project link [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geetika/?source=directory)

Comment: If you want to learn PHP quickly, I recommend lynda - they have a good PHP+MySQL Essentials course that only takes about 11 hrs to complete. http://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/php-with-mysql-essential-training/435-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A4%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Aphp%20mysql%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2%0Ameta_software_facet%3APHP

Comment: And once you have the basics, http://php.net is invaluable as a guide - comparable to MSDN Library help in VS with the addition of community feedback on individual functions. After that, of course, you can always post specific questions here. :)

Comment: Easiest way to search php.net is to google: PHP function_name   ... they're usually the top result.

Comment: Thnaks @steve, you are really a helpful guy, thanks

Comment: Steve, If you dont mind I want to ask you one more thing, I want to put all this function in a class called `tovolt`, and how do I call them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14660/discussion-between-aryang-and-steve)

Comment: Yes its working but one problem `id="top-col" and $TopColClass` also need to change with `module("top-col-", "1,2,3");` . `$TopColClass` counts published modules.

Comment: Please send me your mail and full name so that I can add your name to my framework source code, thanks

Comment: change:

     $TopColClass = 'count-' . $topColCount;
 to
     tovolt::$TopColClass = 'count-' . $topColCount;

Comment: steve if you have time then please see my new question here [my new question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757762/foreach-array-function)

Comment: Still 4 rep shy of being able to comment directly on the (new) question, so I'll put it here. Do you just want a total count of the modules present, or do you need to test it name by name? And, if it is name by name, where will you get the list of names to test? I'm looking at the framework now to see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of them in an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and then use [foreach loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Sometimes just a [for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) might be preferred.